# How can i draw arc with flutter Graphics and how can i rotate that arc?

Tags: flutter

I want to draw this in **Flutter** and did 60% but i'm not sure how to design red arc and animated according to value:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
 class StaticColors {
 static const List<Color> _defaultBarColors = [
    Color.fromRGBO(30, 0, 59, 1.0),
Color.fromRGBO(236, 0, 138, 1.0),
   Color.fromRGBO(98, 133, 218, 1.0),
 ];
 }

class _NewCurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
final double angle;

  final double startAngle;
     final double angleRange;
   final double trackwidth;
  final double shadowWidth;
  final double? shadowstep;
  final Color shadowColor;
  Offset? handler;
  Offset? center;
  late double radius;
  List<Color>? trackColor;
  final bool shadow;

  final bool counterClockwise;
_NewCurvePainter(
  {this.angle = 30,
  this.trackwidth = 10,
  this.trackColor,
  required this.startAngle,
  this.shadowWidth = 10,
  this.shadowstep,
  required this.shadowColor,
  this.shadow = false,
  this.counterClockwise = false,
  required this.angleRange});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
radius = math.min(size.width / 2, size.height / 2) - trackwidth * 0.5;
center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

final progressBarRect = Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.width);

Paint trackPaint;
if (trackColor != null) {
  final trackGradient = SweepGradient(
    startAngle: degreeToRadians(startAngle),
    endAngle: degreeToRadians(360),
    tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
    colors: trackColor!,
  );
  trackPaint = Paint()
    ..shader = trackGradient.createShader(progressBarRect)
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = trackwidth;
} else {
  trackPaint = Paint()
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = trackwidth
    ..color = Colors.grey;
}
drawCircularArc(
    canvas: canvas,
    size: size,
    paint: trackPaint,
    ignoreAngle: true,
    spinnerMode: true);

     if (!shadow) {
  drawShadow(canvas: canvas, size: size);
      }

final currentAngle = counterClockwise ? -angle : angle;
final dynamicGradient = false;
final gradientRotationAngle = dynamicGradient
    ? counterClockwise
        ? startAngle + 10.0
        : startAngle - 10.0
    : 0.0;
      final GradientRotation rotation =
    GradientRotation(degreeToRadians(gradientRotationAngle));

     final gradientStartAngle = dynamicGradient
    ? counterClockwise
        ? 360.0 - currentAngle.abs()
        : 0.0
    : startAngle;
      final gradientEndAngle = dynamicGradient
    ? counterClockwise
        ? 360.0
        : currentAngle.abs()
    : 360;
     final colors = dynamicGradient && counterClockwise
    ? StaticColors._defaultBarColors.reversed.toList()
    : StaticColors._defaultBarColors;

     final progressBarGradient = kIsWeb
    ? LinearGradient(
        tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
        colors: colors,
      )
    : SweepGradient(
        transform: rotation,
        startAngle: degreeToRadians(gradientStartAngle),
        endAngle: degreeToRadians(360),
        tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
        colors: colors,
      );

f. inal progressBarPaint = Paint()
  ..shader = progressBarGradient.createShader(progressBarRect)
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = trackwidth;
drawCircularArc(canvas: canvas, size: size, paint: progressBarPaint);

var dotPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.transparent;

Offset handler = degreesToCoordinates(
    center!, -math.pi / 2 + startAngle + currentAngle + 1.5, radius);
canvas.drawCircle(handler, 10, dotPaint);
  }

  drawCircularArc(
  {required Canvas canvas,
  required Size size,
  required Paint paint,
  bool ignoreAngle = false,
  bool spinnerMode = false}) {
final double angleValue = ignoreAngle ? 0 : (angleRange - angle);
final range = counterClockwise ? -angleRange : angleRange;
final currentAngle = counterClockwise ? angleValue : -angleValue;
canvas.drawArc(
    Rect.fromCircle(center: center!, radius: radius),
    degreeToRadians(spinnerMode ? 0 : startAngle),
    degreeToRadians(spinnerMode ? 360 : range + currentAngle),
    false,
    paint);
   }

   drawShadow({required Canvas canvas, required Size size}) {
final shadowStep = shadowstep != null
    ? shadowstep!
    : math.max(1, (shadowWidth - trackwidth) ~/ 10);
final maxOpacity = math.min(1.0, 2);
final repetitions = math.max(1, ((shadowWidth - trackwidth) ~/ shadowStep));
final opacityStep = maxOpacity / repetitions;
final shadowPaint = Paint()
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
for (int i = 1; i <= repetitions; i++) {
  shadowPaint.strokeWidth = trackwidth + i * shadowStep;
  if (StaticColors._defaultBarColors.first == primaryColor) {
    shadowPaint.color = Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0);
  } else {
    shadowPaint.color = StaticColors._defaultBarColors.first == redColor
        ? Colors.transparent
        : shadowColor.withOpacity(maxOpacity - (opacityStep * (i - 1)));
  }

  drawCircularArc(canvas: canvas, size: size, paint: shadowPaint);
    }
    }

 @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
    }
 }
```

You can edit values according to yourself

[Sleek Circular Slider](https://github.com/matthewfx/sleek_circular_slider)
also the package you can look into clone the repo and modify it according to you need